# Need help understanding the flow of a python script on github repository

Tags: python

[OpenDroneMap](https://www.opendronemap.org) is an open source command line toolkit to generate maps, point clouds, 3D models and DEMs from drone, balloon or kite images, here's their github link [OpenDroneMap/ODM](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/ODM)

Was pointed out to a file [ODM/blob/master/stages/odm_app.py](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/ODM/blob/master/stages/odm_app.py), which seems to have the `Initializes the application and defines the ODM application pipeline stages`.

How to I go about understanding the the entire process flow of the entire pipe line?

I understand that UML (Unified Modelling Language) can be used as a first step.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: When it comes to python understanding what a code actually does can be pretty hard as Payton has not static types. Therefore the best understanding you can get when using step-by-step debugging on the relevant parts you are interested in. Make very tiny example and process it while you are watching it in the debugger. A nice GUI like PyCharm may be helpful for debugging and inspecting. Load your project into PyCharm and execute it in debug mode and use breakpoints where you don't understand something.